# MYSQL JOIN two columns with one and get data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, new-operator

FIXED! sorry to waste anyones time :P

> im trying to get two colums joined with one with mysql in PHP
>
> ```
> $result = $link->query('SELECT Software.*, 
> Genre.Naam AS Genre, 
> Console.Naam AS ConsoleNaam,
> Draager.Naam AS MediumNaam,
> Studio.Naam AS StudioNaam,
> Publisher.Naam AS PublisherNaam
> FROM Software
> INNER JOIN Genre ON Genre.Genre_ID = Software.Genre_ID
> INNER JOIN Console ON Console.Console_ID = Software.Console_ID
> INNER JOIN Draager ON Draager.Draager_ID = Software.Medium_ID
> INNER JOIN Company AS Studio ON Software.Studio_ID = Studio.Company_ID
> INNER JOIN Company AS Publisher ON Software.Publisher_ID = Publisher.Company_ID
> ');
> ```
>
> Table Company has to join with Table Software on there ID's to get the
>   name of the Company.
>
> Any tips on what i have to change to the script above to get it to
>   work?

Comment: the spelling of jion (Join) on your last two inner Jion...

Comment: can you post atleast a little schema of you tables?

Comment: LOL! 3 hours wasted because im dyslectic. THANX!

Comment: so was the Spelling the wrong thing or is there more still incorrect?  Not a waste if it helped you; but please select the checkmark next to the response that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have an answer:

JION is spelled JOIN when relating tables :D

```
$result = $link->query('SELECT Software.*, 
Genre.Naam AS Genre, 
Console.Naam AS ConsoleNaam,
Draager.Naam AS MediumNaam,
Studio.Naam AS StudioNaam,
Publisher.Naam AS PublisherNaam
FROM Software
INNER JOIN Genre ON Genre.Genre_ID = Software.Genre_ID
INNER JOIN Console ON Console.Console_ID = Software.Console_ID
INNER JOIN Draager ON Draager.Draager_ID = Software.Medium_ID
INNER JOIN Company AS Studio ON Software.Studio_ID = Studio.Company_ID
INNER JOIN Company AS Publisher ON Software.Publisher_ID = Publisher.Company_ID
');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.  `JOIN` misspelled as `JION`:

```
$result = $link->query('SELECT Software.*, 
Genre.Naam AS Genre, 
Console.Naam AS ConsoleNaam,
Draager.Naam AS MediumNaam,
Studio.Naam AS StudioNaam,
Publisher.Naam AS PublisherNaam
FROM Software
INNER JOIN Genre ON Genre.Genre_ID = Software.Genre_ID
INNER JOIN Console ON Console.Console_ID = Software.Console_ID
INNER JOIN Draager ON Draager.Draager_ID = Software.Medium_ID
/* Misspelled JOIN below *(/
INNER JOIN Company AS Studio ON Software.Studio_ID = Studio.Company_ID
INNER JOIN Company AS Publisher ON Software.Publisher_ID = Publisher.Company_ID
');
```

Comment: Thnx i overlooked that. workin on fixing it for 3 hours and thats it :P